# Schema method for all Schema's - Mongoose method inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working in nodejs with Mongoose, at this moment I have data in different collections with _id like string writing for the user, I try to make a refactor of this and generate _id automatically.

I want have in other file js only function generateID( return _id; ); and implement this function in all models without write over and over in all models.

This is bus.js

```
/***********************************Bus Model**********************************/

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    merge    = require('merge'),
    global   = require('./schema/global');

/***********************************Schema******************************************/
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var busSchema = new Schema({});

/***********************************Methods*****************************************/
var bus = mongoose.model('Bus', busSchema);

/**
 * extend functions from global
 * we do this to prevent duplicate code
 */
merge(bus.schema.methods, global.schema.methods);

module.exports = bus;
```

And this is global.js in schema folder over models folder in project

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var globalSchema = new Schema({});

function objectIdAsString() {
    return mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toString();
}

globalSchema.methods.objectIdAsString = objectIdAsString;;

module.exports = mongoose.model('global', globalSchema);
```

And in route.js have this implementation:

```
var bus = new Bus();

bus._id = bus.objectIdAsString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is creating a Mongoose plugin

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html

global.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = exports = function objectIdAsString(schema) {
  schema.methods.objectIdAsString = function objectIdAsString() {
    return mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toString();
  };
}
```

bus.js

```
/***********************************Bus Model**********************************/

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    merge    = require('merge'),
    global   = require('./schema/global');

/***********************************Schema******************************************/
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var busSchema = new Schema({});
/**
 * extend functions from global
 * we do this to prevent duplicate code
 */
busSchema.plugin(global);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bus', busSchema);
```

Somewhere else:

```
var bus = new bus();
console.log(bus.objectIdAsString());
```

Is working and outputting the correct values for me:

```
566b35a02a54c60e168c3a9f
566b35a02a54c60e168c3aa1
566b35a02a54c60e168c3aa3
.....
```

Comment: Ummmmmm Ok I try with this and tell you if is work for me.

Comment: @AndrsAvelinoMonasterioMoren let me know if it works. I tried it myself and the generateID function is accessible in the Model class.. Just replace the contents of generateID with your own code

Comment: Doesn't work,  merge(bus.schema.methods, global.schema.methods);  __v: 93 } has no method 'objectIdAsString'
    at Query.<anonymous> (/home/developer/rube/server/routes.js:1017:35)
    at /home/developer/rube/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:177:19
    at /home/developer/rube/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:109:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)

Comment: Yes npm install merge

Comment: How do you call the function on bus?

Comment: Ummm really not I see this. The problem that I have is in production environment when I have buses with string _id wrote for users, now I want the _id will generate for the system using a unique id, I solve this creating a method in bus schema but I want use this solution in other schemas with the same problem but using the same code.

Comment: Ok, I go to prove and I tell you.